# Creating cv elements with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I want to make a div which includes my experience. 
[image: See the example]

So I tried making a div (wrapper) which includes `span` for each word. Then I tried on each element with `nth-child` to give a style `justify-content: flex-end;`

The element goes to the end indeed, but the next element does not take it place. So if I try to `flex-end` the 'verkoopmedewerker' it goes to the right but a break appears at its previous place so 'plaats' will have a gap between 'functie' and itself.

How can I achieve what the picture shows?

[See my DEMO here](https://jsfiddle.net/um2fL1nv/)

```css
.baan {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
}

.baan :nth-child(3) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h3>Bijbaan</h3>
<div class="baan">
  <strong>Lidl</strong>
  <span>Functie</span>
  <span class="rechts">Verkoopmedewerker</span>
  <span>Plaats</span>
  <span class="rechts">Almeloplein 73
          2533 AD, Den Haag
          Part-time, 54 uur P. week
          </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible flexbox solution:

```
.baan {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
}

.baan span{
  flex: 1 1 50%; /*change width if you don't want the same width for every "span"*/
}

.baan strong{
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.baan .rechts{
  text-align:right;
}
```

However, I think CSS-grid is better in your case 'cause works in 2 directions: rows and columns. Flexbox works well only in one direction and you have "to hack" this limit if you want it works like grid.